# Ruby mongo driver dynamic query results undefined method for Mongo::Collection

Tags: ruby, mongodb, mongodb-query

I want to pass this collection name and options dynamically based on the user's input.

```
query = "test_collection.find.skip(2).limit(100)"
collection, options = query.split(".", 2)
   => ["test_collection", "find.skip(2).limit(100)"]
```

```
Mongo::Client.new("mongodb+srv://user:pass@clusteruri.net/testdb?w=majority&connectTimeoutMS=123") do |conn|  
 rows << conn[collection].send(options).to_a
end
```

undefined method `find.skip(2).limit(100)' for #Mongo::Collection:0x00007xxx20

This works fine when options = "find" though. Multiple options are not working I think.
Tried

- rows << conn[collection].options.to_a => empty result
- rows <<
  conn[collection].send(*options).to_a => undefined method error
- rows << conn[collection].send(**options).to_a => no implicit conversion of String into Hash

How do pass in the chained method dynamically>

Answer (score 1):

`send` requires specifying the method name as the first argument and parameters as additional arguments. It doesn't take a string that contains the name, arguments and required punctuation. The closest thing that would work for the question as stated is `eval`.

However, `eval` of *user input* is **extremely dangerous**. You are likely to allow users to, for example, delete all of your data.

You should parse the options out of the user-provided input, match them against a whitelist (e.g. the list of `skip`, `limit`, etc.), validate the parameters if necessary, and construct appropriate invocations.